# Different results obtained on a regression model fitted on a database from different versions of XGBoost

Tags: python, xgboost, hyperparameters

I have wrote a code in python to do some regression work with **XGBoost** but when I run the code on two different computers with two different versions of **XGBoost** and **Python**, the results are drastically different. My code is long but I would like to show some parts of it here. The parts I am presenting here are the hyperparameter tuning using **xgb.cv()** command and fitting and prediction using **Scikit's** **XGBRegressor** with the optimized parameters obtained by the hyperparameter tuning. The parameters  that will be tuned are stored in the following list with an initial arbitary value:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn import preprocessing
from model_functions import GaussRankScaler
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score, mean_squared_error
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from math import sqrt
import xgboost as xgb
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
import shap
import operator
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
import joblib
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import scipy as sp
import seaborn as sns
from numpy import asarray
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn import linear_model
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
import scipy.stats as stats
from yellowbrick.regressor import residuals_plot, ResidualsPlot
import sys
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

params = {
    'max_depth': 6,
    'min_child_weight': 1,
    'learning_rate': 0.3,
    'subsample': 1,
    'colsample_bytree': 1,
    'objective': 'reg:squarederror',
    'eval_metric': 'rmse',
    'booster': 'gbtree',
    'nthread': -1,
    'validate_parameters':'True',
    'alpha': 0.2,
    'lambda': 0.001,
    'colsample_bylevel': 0.9,
    'verbose': 0,
    'gamma': 0.01,
    'max_delta_step': 0.1,
    'silent': 0
}
```

The parameter tuning is done as mentioned below using a *for loop*. In every loop, two of the parameters are tuned except for `learning rate` and `gamma` where they are optimized individually. Each two parameters will be optimized in a for loop and the list of parameters would be updated with the best value optimized for them at the end of each loop. The loops are similar with the only difference between them being the parameters optimized. **xgb.cv()** is used for the *cross validation* part of the process. The evaluation metrics used to choose the best value for each parameter is **RMSE**. The following is the loop that is responsible for optimizing `learning rate` (AKA `eta`):

```
df_x = dfnum.iloc[:,:-1]

df_y = dfnum.iloc[:,-1]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(df_x, df_y,
                                                   test_size=0.1,
                                                   random_state=42)    

"Converting features' distributions to normal distribution"

gauss_scaler = GaussRankScaler()

X_trainnum = gauss_scaler.fit_transform(X_train)

X_testnum = gauss_scaler.transform(X_test)

"Scaling all the features to be between 0 and 1"    

scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
    
X_trainnum = scaler.fit_transform(X_trainnum)

X_testnum = scaler.transform(X_testnum)


num_boost_round = 999
    
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X_trainnum, label=y_train)
dtest = xgb.DMatrix(X_testnum, label=y_test)

min_rmse = float("Inf")
best_params = None

for learning_rate in [.3, .2, .1, .05, .01, .005]:

    params['learning_rate'] = learning_rate
    
    cv_results = xgb.cv(
            params,
            dtrain,
            num_boost_round=num_boost_round,
            seed=42,
            nfold=3,
            metrics=['rmse'],
            early_stopping_rounds=10
          )

    mean_rmse = cv_results['test-rmse-mean'].min()
    boost_rounds = cv_results['test-rmse-mean'].argmin()

    if mean_rmse < min_rmse:
        min_rmse = mean_rmse
        best_params = learning_rate

print('')
print("Best parameter: learning_rate = {}, RMSE: {}".format(best_params, min_rmse))
print('')

params['learning_rate'] = best_params
```

After all the parameters are tuned in the above fashion, the updated and optimized list of parameters is passed through the **XGBRegressor** and the model is fitted on the database at hand:

```
print('Fitting the model')

best_model = XGBRegressor(**params,early_stopping_rounds=10,num_boost_round=999)

best_model.fit(X_trainnum, y_train)

joblib.dump(best_model,'best_model_grid')

y_pred = best_model.predict(X_testnum)

y_pred1 = best_model.predict(X_trainnum)
```

I am using **Python** and **XGBoost** through **Anaconda** on both of my machines (personal lap top and my office PC). The **XGBoost** version on my lap top is *0.90* and the **Python** version is *3.7.10*. My office PC on the other hand, runs the *3.8.11* version of **Python** and *1.42* version of **XGBoost**.

When running my code on my personal lap top with the older version of **Python** and **XGBoost**, the code runs smoothly without any warnings or errors. However, when it is ran on my office PC with newer versions of the **Python** and **XGBoost**, at each step of the for loops containing **xgb.cv()** command, designed to do the hyperparameter tuning, I receive this error message:

```
[13:38:44] WARNING: D:\bld\xgboost-split_1631904903843\work\src\learner.cc:573: 
Parameters: { "early_stoppage" } might not be used.

  This may not be accurate due to some parameters are only used in language bindings but
  passed down to XGBoost core.  Or some parameters are not used but slip through this
  verification. Please open an issue if you find above cases.
```

The error messages would then change to:

```
Hyperparameter tuning.
[13:38:47] WARNING: D:\bld\xgboost-split_1631904903843\work\src\learner.cc:573: 
Parameters: { "silent", "verbose" } might not be used.

  This may not be accurate due to some parameters are only used in language bindings but
  passed down to XGBoost core.  Or some parameters are not used but slip through this
  verification. Please open an issue if you find above cases.
```

And finally, when the model is fitted with **XGBRegressor**, it changes to:

```
[15:08:00] WARNING: D:\bld\xgboost-split_1631904903843\work\src\learner.cc:573: 
Parameters: { "early_stopping_rounds", "num_boost_round", "silent", "verbose" } might not be used.

  This may not be accurate due to some parameters are only used in language bindings but
  passed down to XGBoost core.  Or some parameters are not used but slip through this
  verification. Please open an issue if you find above cases.
```

The results obtained on the older versions of the algorithm and programing language used in this project, are much better than the results obtained through the newer version. The older version yields much better results than the newer version. The difference is very Significant. The database I work with consists of *11* numerical features and a numerical target feature.

I have researched and browsed on this website and other sources and sought help from a number of data analyst experts on this, but unfortunately I have not been able to find a solution or a reason for this problem.

I would be really thankful and appreciative if someone could help me with this issue

Comment: It is learned from the warning that although the parameters of the old version are retained, they are not used in the new version, which is why you received the warning but did not receive the error. and because the parameters are not used, the code of the new version is invalid. You can look at the old and new source code to confirm the error.

Comment: @lazy I have removed those parameters. my model is now working better but it is overfitting. I suspect it is because of the absence of the "early stoppage" and "number of boosting rounds" which I do not know hot to implement it within the new version for xgb.train()

Answer (score 1):

I will focus on this snippet of code:

```py
best_model = XGBRegressor(**params,early_stopping_rounds=10,num_boost_round=999)
```

The correct version should be:

```py
# Removed `verbose`, `eval_metric`.  Replaced `nthread` with `n_jobs`.
# Replaced objective to "reg:squarederror" since you are using regression instead of classification.
params = {
    'max_depth': 6,
    'min_child_weight': 1,
    'eta': 0.3,
    'subsample': 1,
    'colsample_bytree': 1,
    "objective": "reg:squarederror",
    'booster': 'gbtree',
    'n_jobs': 10,
    'validate_parameters':'True',
    'alpha': 0.2,
    'lambda': 0.001,
    'colsample_bylevel': 0.9,
    'gamma': 0.01,
    'max_delta_step': 0.1,
}

# notice the `n_estimators`
model = XGBRegressor(**params, n_estimators=999)

# Passed `early_stopping_rounds`, `verbose`, `eval_metric` here.
# Replaced the `eval_metric` to `rmse` since you are using regression instead of classification.
# Added `eval_set` since you need to carry out evaluation.
model.fit(
    X,
    y,
    early_stopping_rounds=10,
    verbose=True,
    eval_metric="rmse",
    eval_set=[(X, y)],
)
```

You can find the document of the estimator here https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.sklearn .